# Two definitions of recurrent and transient stochastic states

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

On a finite state space $\{1,\cdots,M \}$, I have seen two definitions of a transient/recurrent state for a Markov Process.

1. Let $p_n(i,j) = \mathbb{P}(X_n=j | X_0=i)$. Then $\sum\limits_{n\ge 0} p_n(i,i) = \infty \iff$ state $i$ is recurrent.
2. Let $A(j)$ be the set of states that is reachable from $j$. Then $i$ is recurrent if and only if $j\in A(i) \rightarrow i\in A(j)$ (converse needs not be true)

I have a messy proof on how to prove they are equivalent and here is a sketch.

First in an irreducible finite state space, a random walk starting anywhere reaches all states infinitely many times almost surely (with probability 1). Therefore, if (2) holds then we can see that $A(i)$ is an irreducible state space because anything in $A(i)$ can go back to $i$, so from any state $k\in A(i)$, we know all states in $A(i)$ are accessible from $k$.

Now, if (2) doesn't hold, we want to show a Markov Process starting from $i$ steps out of $A(i)$ almost surely. Fix $k\in A(i)$ such that $i$ is NOT accessible from $k$. Consider an alternate Markov Process that changes the destinations some directed weighted edges in the transition graph and **$S$=all states in $A(i)$ that communicates to $i$** is an irreducible state space where all states are recurrent. This implies that in this original process, there exists a state in $S$, call $s$ such that $p_1(s,k) > 0$. If we are lucky enough to never step out of $S$ if we don't go from $s$ to $k$ (note $k$ cannot go back to any of the states in $S$), we visit $s$ infinitely many times and each time we may go to $k$. The probability we visit $s$ $m$ times and don't go to $k$ is $(1-p_1(s,k))^m$. This should imply that $\sum\limits_{n\ge 0} \mathbb{P}(X_n\in S| X_0=i)$ is finite, as needed.

My questions are:

1. Is this proof correct or does it not have rigor issues?
2. Does the same result hold for an countably infinite state space?